# Add transition without sender and receiver Qt 5.2

Tags: c++, qt, transition, state

I implemented a three state machine and declared a function that change the current state of the machine:
    void changeState(s1);
that contains the following command in order to change machine state:
    s0->addTransition(s1)
When I compile it no error appears, but when I run the application the following message appears:

QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

Shall I neccesarily connect the trnasition to a signal?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Luca

Comment: You're running your state machine in a separate thread, right?

Answer (score 0):

With what you explained, I would tell the issue is not from the connection itself. QT doesn't accept parent/child to be located in different thread. This means your whole state machine has to run in one single thread.

In order to run it in a thread different than the main thread you need to create your QStatemachine without parent, add all state and then move it to a different thread using QObject::moveToThread.

You may also fully create your state machine from an other thread altrough I never did that. Creating element in the main is most of the time a more straight forward implementation. You may then move them as you want.

And yes, you may add transition without signals. In this case the state just has to be activate by other means, by reimplementing [QAbstractTransition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracttransition.html#details).